# How to check if any checkbox has been selected

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I would like to see if any checkbox in a particular div has been selected, so as to proceed with a multiphase form I am working on.  Currently whether a checkbox is selected or not, I am getting the alert "Tile selected".

HTML code

```
<div class='material' id='material1'>
     <a class='product'><div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/tile2.jpg);'><input class='select_all' id='tile' type='checkbox' name='1marm' value='Verde Guatemala'></div><p>Verde Guatemala</p></a>
     <a class='product'><div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/tile1.jpg);'><input class='select_all' id='tile' type='checkbox' name='1marm' value='Bianco Carrara'></div><p>Bianco Carrara</p></a>
</div>

<button type="button" class="nasta" onClick="processStep1()">Nasta</button>
```

jquery code

```
var tile;
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}

function processStep1(){
    tile = _("tile").value;
    if(!("tiles_bg input:checked").length) {
    /*  _("step1").style.display = "none";
        _("step2").style.display = "block"; */
        alert(tile);
    } else {
        alert("Tiles selected");    
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you have two id(s) with the same value (title) ? Isn't id supposed to be a unique attribute??

Comment: if ($("#checkboxid").is(":checked")) alert("Tiles selected");

Comment: Thank you both for your help found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use the class instead of id:

($(".checkboxclass").is(":checked")) alert("Tiles selected");

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is:

```js
var tile;
function _(x){
  return document.getElementById(x);
}

function processStep1(){
  tile = _("tile").value;
  if(!$('#material1').find("input.select_all:checked").length) { // look for checked inside div
    /*  _("step1").style.display = "none";
                 _("step2").style.display = "block"; */
    alert(tile);
  } else {
    alert("Tiles selected");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>


<div class='material' id='material1'>
    <a class='product'><div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/tile2.jpg);'><input class='select_all' id='tile' type='checkbox' name='1marm' value='Verde Guatemala'></div><p>Verde Guatemala</p></a>
    <a class='product'><div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/tile1.jpg);'><input class='select_all' id='tile' type='checkbox' name='1marm' value='Bianco Carrara'></div><p>Bianco Carrara</p></a>
</div>

<button type="button" class="nasta" onClick="processStep1()">Nasta</button>
```